# How to backup current dotfiles?

Tags: macos, bash, dotfiles

I just purchased a mac and installed dotfiles from an external source, which screwed up my terminal settings. Luckily I had made a backup of my system with time machine so I simply reinstalled the whole system.

However it would make more sense to just backup the original dotfiles of the system to reinstall those if there's a problem with custom ones.

- Is there such a thing as 'original dotfiles'?
- If so, where are they, and how best can I back them up?
- If not, how would I reverse any changes made by new ones?

Answer (score 3):

The macOS skeleton directories are in `/System/Library/User Template/`, and can only be viewed by the root user.

However, (by default) new macOS user accounts **don't have** any dot files (you can test this by creating a new user account):

```
Aoide:~ admin$ sudo ls -la /Users/testaccount/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x+ 11 testaccount  staff   374 Apr 21 13:13 .
drwxr-xr-x   8 root         admin   272 Apr 21 13:12 ..
-r--------   1 testaccount  staff     7 Apr 21 13:12 .CFUserTextEncoding
drwx------+  3 testaccount  staff   102 Apr 21 13:12 Desktop
drwx------+  3 testaccount  staff   102 Apr 21 13:12 Documents
drwx------+  3 testaccount  staff   102 Apr 21 13:12 Downloads
drwx------@ 46 testaccount  staff  1564 Apr 21 13:13 Library
drwx------+  3 testaccount  staff   102 Apr 21 13:12 Movies
drwx------+  3 testaccount  staff   102 Apr 21 13:12 Music
drwx------+  3 testaccount  staff   102 Apr 21 13:12 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  5 testaccount  staff   170 Apr 21 13:12 Public
```

Like l0b0 says, you should use one of many available options to version or backup your own dot files. If you have trouble, just delete them to restore the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The original dotfiles are in the skeleton directory, usually `/etc/skel`:

```
$ ls -A /etc/skel
.bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc  .emacs  .mozilla
```

`useradd`, for example, uses this directory to set up new users. If you want to restore file contents to the original, you can simply copy the file over your existing dotfile and restart your shell.

There is no "standard" way to back them up. You can simply copy them to a different directory, use a version control system, or try any of probably thousands of *nix-compatible backup software packages.

If `/etc/skel` doesn't exist, have a look for the `SKEL` variable in `/etc/default/useradd`, or just `find /etc -name '*bashrc*'`.

Comment: Thanks! however there is no skeleton directory in my etc folder... any idea where else it might be? I'm on mac OSsierra